# javascript/jquery loop through divs and add next/prev buttons with click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

```
<div class="form">
   <div class="step">This is step 1</div>
   <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
   <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
   <div class="step">This is step 4</div>

   <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
   <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

I know how to loop through the divs and get each div not a big deal, but I don't see the logic on how to loop through the divs and show only the first one, and then onclick next show the second one and so on (and same for previous).

Either vanilla JS or jQuery solutions are fine as solutions but what I'm really  looking for is if any of you can explain me the exact logic behind it, because I can't really see it.

I can post some code that I've done but that's not the problem, but in how to program it logic

Thank you so much

Comment: why are you guys down voting this?? isn't stackoverflow a ask for advice/solutions as well?? I'll paste in all the code I've done so far will that make you stop downvoting?? did all of you were born experts?

Comment: What are you trying to show? Can you explain what you are attempting to accomplish? Do you want to use something like jquery in order to help you show and hide divs? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ The accordion tool could be used to show and hide divs and you could add a button to open each. I think this question needs more explanation.

Comment: @Aaron I get your point and the reason I didn't share the code is that I wasn't looking for the actual code but for the logic behind it to understand it and build it myself, that's all I'm still missing after those answers, cause I found similar answers on other topics as well, but not the logic explained

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `:visible` to find the DIV that's currently being shown, and `.next()` and `.prev()` to go forward and backward.

```js
$("#nextBtn").click(function() {
  var nextDiv = $(".step:visible").next(".step");
  if (nextDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to beginning
    nextDiv = $(".step:first");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  nextDiv.show();
});

$("#prevBtn").click(function() {
  var prevDiv = $(".step:visible").prev(".step");
  if (prevDiv.length == 0) { // wrap around to end
    prevDiv = $(".step:last");
  }
  $(".step").hide();
  prevDiv.show();
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}
div.step:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
  <div class="step">This is step 1</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
  <div class="step">This is step 4</div>

  <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I've accepted @Barmar solution because he answered first, and thank you very much for all the answers guys, you rock

Comment: How do you add code snippets to posts?!!!!

Comment: @Aaron The 7th tool from the left in the SO editor toolbar. The icon looks like a document with `<>` in it.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would try to solve this problem using few useful methods like [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`prev`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) and [`last`](http://api.jquery.com/last/) + in conjunction with CSS `active` class to show current block.

```js
var $steps = $('.step');

$('#nextBtn').click(function() {
    var $next = $steps.filter('.active').removeClass('active').next('.step');
    if (!$next.length) $next = $steps.first();
    $next.addClass('active');
});

$('#prevBtn').click(function() {
    var $prev = $steps.filter('.active').removeClass('active').prev('.step');
    if (!$prev.length) $prev = $steps.last();
    $prev.addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.step {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #DDD;
    display: none;
}
.step.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">
    <div class="step active">This is step 1</div>
    <div class="step">This is step 2</div>
    <div class="step">This is step 3</div>
    <div class="step">This is step 4</div>
    <button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
    <button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had tried using the index based code. try it

```
       var index = 0;
    $(function () {
        $('.step:not(:first)').hide();
        $('#nextBtn').click(function () {
            if (($('.step').length - 1) >= index) {
                $('.step:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
                index++;
                $('.step:eq(' + index + ')').show();
            }
        });
        $('#prevBtn').click(function () {
            if (index != 0) {
                $('.step:eq(' + index + ')').hide();
                index--;
                $('.step:eq(' + index + ')').show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Instead of `$('.step:eq(' + index + ')').hide();` I suggest just using `$('.step').hide();`. Also, you can avoid building the selectors with `$('.step').eq(index)`

Comment: $('.step').hide(); will call for the all the div but when we use $('.step').eq(index) it will call for that particular index if it is wrong can you explain me what is wrong?

Comment: No, that's right. `$('.step').hide();` will hide all of them. This should have the same performance as `$('.step').eq(index).hide();`, but don't quote me on that. And it comes with the added benefit of ensuring that only one is shown at a time (in case there are any bugs introduced).